# Is it possible to do this.Sort(p => p.ID); or something similar?

Tags: c#, linq

In a class inherited from `List<>`, How it could be sorted by a key selector (like Order by).

```
public class BusinessRuleCollection : List<BusinessRule>
{
    Read()
    {
         // After the reading here, I wonder if I could do the following:
         this.Sort(p => p.ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite - `Sort` takes a `Comparison<T>` (or `IComparer<T>`) and `p => p.ID` isn't convertible to `Comparison<T>`. You can do:

```
Sort((p, q) => p.ID.CompareTo(q.ID))
```

though. Or in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) I have a `ProjectionComparer` implementation of `IComparer<T>`, so you'd use something like:

```
Sort(ProjectionComparer<BusinessRule>.Create(p => p.ID));
```

Answer (score 6):

You could add an extension method:

```
public static void Sort<TSource,TValue>(
    this List<TSource> list,
    Func<TSource,TValue> selector)
{
    var comparer = Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    list.Sort((x,y) => comparer.Compare(
        selector(x), selector(y)));
}
```

Which should do it.